# Getting the status of the internet/network on iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, network-programming, reachability

I have this code:

```
BOOL status = ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus] != NotReachable);
```

But for some reason it always returns YES even though I have my device on airplane mode with cellular data off and my computer with Wifi off.  The notification center code works just fine:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

self.reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

[self.reachability startNotifier];
```

What gives?

Comment: What version of Reachability.h/m are you using? I've tested it on 3.0 its visible in the .h's comment section.

Comment: All I see is this: /*
 Copyright (c) 2011, Tony Million.
 All rights reserved.

Comment: And my network status is saying when run: ReachableViaWiFi

Comment: Try the reachability files from here https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Or check you have the latest code from Tony Million's git repo.

Comment: When I switch to apple's reachability, I get an error here: self.reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

Comment: What's the error? is self.reachability referencing Apple's class?

Answer (score 2):

Your device may reachable via  `ReachableViaWWAN or ReachableViaWiFi`

there are three `NetworkStatus` available.

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
    NotReachable = 0,
    ReachableViaWiFi,
    ReachableViaWWAN
} NetworkStatus;


/*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 This method is used to provide wifi network current status.
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
- (NetworkStatus *)notifyNetworkStatus:(Reachability *)reachability
{
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    NSString* statusString = @"Network Mode Changed / Connection closed!!";

    @try
    {
        switch (netStatus)
        {
            case NotReachable:
            {
                statusString = @"No network Access!! Connection closed";
                break;
            }
            case ReachableViaWWAN:
            {
                statusString = @"Network Mode Changed / Connection reachable only via WWAN!!";
                break;
            }
            case ReachableViaWiFi:
            {
                statusString = @"Network Mode Changed / Connection reachable via WiFi";
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                break;
            } 

        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s\n Exception: Name- %@ Reason->%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[exception name],[exception reason]);
    }
}
```

Download and check [developer.apple.com- Reachability application](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Reachability.zip)